# The support of a the sum of random independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The **support** of a continuous random variable is the set of the outcomes such that $f(x)>0$. If $X$ has support $[a,b]$ and $Y$ has support $[c,d]$ and they are independent, what is the support of $X+Y$?

I can think through this with examples and realize that the support of $X+Y$ is going to be $[a+c, b+d]$ by thinking about the maximum and minimum possibilities, but how would you show this with a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $X+Y$ is the convolution of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.  If we let $Z = X+Y$, then we write

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) F_Y(z-x) \, dx
$$

For any $z \in (a+c, b+d)$, we claim that the interval $I = [\max\{a, z-d\}, \min\{b, z-c\}]$ has positive length, and that the product in the integral is positive in that interval, and therefore that the integral itself is positive.  First, for the applicable $z$, $z-d < b+d-d = b$, $z-d < z-c$, and $z-c > a+c-c = a$, so the interval has positive length.  Next, $I$ is clearly a subset of $[a, b]$, so $f_X(x)$ is positive within it; $z-x$ falls in the interval $[\max\{c, z-b\}, \min\{d, z-a\}]$, which is a subset of $[c, d]$, so $f_Y(z-x)$ is positive for $I$, too.  Since the integrand is positive over an interval of positive length, the integral is positive.

Note that the support as you've defined it only extends over the open interval.  At the endpoints, you're only "clipping the corner" of the rectangle and the value of the integral is zero: The sums $a+c$ and $b+d$ are achieved with probability zero (but it is not impossible—the events merely have probability measure zero).

Comment: Are the closed-interval square brackets (denoting closed intervals) an addition to this since you answered?

Comment: I don't think I've made any changes.  Why do you ask?

Comment: The question has closed intervals, you answer deals with open ones. Just wondering of the question had been changed after your answer.

Comment: I'm claiming that if you define the support as the interval over which the probability is positive, then the support is actually an open interval (not including the endpoints).  For instance, the only way to get $X + Y = a+c$ is for $X = a$ and $Y = c$ exactly.  Unless there are impulses in the PDF for $X$ and $Y$ at those two points, the probability of that sum is zero.  A similar observation goes for $b+d$.

Comment: I fixed the exposition; hopefully, it should be clear why the probability is positive only over the open interval $(a+c, b+d)$.